# R and R markdown Version Information

Tags: r, r-markdown, version

I used to do coding with python, and kind of habituated with it. I want to  learn more about other languages and their libraries. So, I wannna switch to R and R markdown. And I was searching the similarity between R and  Python. When we want to learn any python project we are going through **requirement.txt and setup.py** file to get idea about the library and predefined methods version and info as followed.
[image]

**Is there any same file(requirement.txt and setup.py) or way of representaion about library and method with their version for R and R Markdown?**
Thank you all, Happy Coding.

**Is there any same file(requirement.txt and setup.py in python) or way of representaion about library and method with their version for R and R Markdown?**

Comment: Look at the [`renv`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/renv/index.html) package (and, historically, the [`packrat`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/packrat/index.html) package). They operate (very) differently than python's `requirement.txt` but provide the same effect: strict versioning of dependency packages.

Answer (score 0):

The index page of each R package on CRAN shows requirements such as R version and package versions, see [the example of the R package "ggplot"](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggplot2/index.html).

Any R script that uses some library (such as ggplot2) will have the dependencies and requirements listed in the index pages of the R packages used.